# WSO2 MI dataService nested queries with multiple parameters

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

How to pass multiple parameters into WSO2 MI dataService, nested queries

Answer (score 0):

I search far and wide,
Here how its done:

```
</query>  
    <query id="getCampaigns" useConfig="MySQLConnection">
    <sql>SELECT NULL</sql>
    <param name="param1" sqlType="STRING" />
    <param name="param2" sqlType="QUERY_STRING" />
    <param name="param3" sqlType="QUERY_STRING" />
    <result outputType="json">{
  "Campaigns": {
    "CampaignsByBanks": {
        "SearchedCampaigns": {
          "@getCampaignBbank": "$param1->param1, $param2->param2, $param3->param3",
          "@getCampaignAbank": "$param1->param1, $param2->param2, $param3->param3"
        },
        "OtherCampaigns": {
          "@getOtherCampaignBbank": "$param1->param1, $param2->param2, $param3->param3",
          "@getOtherCampaignAbank": "$param1->param1, $param2->param2, $param3->param3"
        }
    }
  }
}
    </result>
  </query>
```

how to pass single parameter into WSO2 MI dataService, nested query
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI630/Defining+Nested+Queries